# Returning an fstream

Tags: c++, fstream, move-semantics, rvo

I have this function:

```
fstream open_user_file() const
{
    ...
}
```

but my compiler complains about `fstream` copy-constructor being implicitly deleted. Given that the compiler performs RVO, why is the copy constructor chosen instead of the move constructor?

Otherwise, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: RVO requires the type to be copyable.

Comment: @0x499602D2 is there a reason why?

Comment: Not sure exactly, but the standard mandates that a copy-constructor be accessible even if it would be optimized away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The currently accepted answer is just wrong.

When returning a local variable with automatic storage, of the same type as the declared return type of the function, then there is a two phase process going on:

```
fstream open_user_file() const
{
    fstream f;

    /*...*/

    return f;
}
```

1. The selection of the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue.
2. If the first overload resolution fails or was not performed, or if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is not an rvalue reference to the object’s type (possibly cv-qualified), overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an lvalue.

This means that if `f` is move constructible, that will be preferred (and possibly elided) for returning `f`.  Else if `f` is copy constructible that will be done (and possibly elided) for returning `f`.  Otherwise `f` can not be returned from this function and a compile-time error should result.

The only case in which:

```
return std::move(f);
```

should help is when the implementation is buggy.  In a conforming implementation, `fstream`  is move constructible and:

```
return f;
```

will be optimal.  If `f` is not move constructible, then:

```
return std::move(f);
```

won't help in a conforming implementation.  And if coded anyway in a conforming implementation will have the effect of a pessimization, in that it will inhibit RVO.

gcc 4.8 has not implemented movable streams (and streams are not copyable).  And this is the source of your problem.  In C++98, C++03, and gcc 4.8, streams are not returnable from functions.  In C++11 they are.

Comment: http://bpaste.net/show/222137/ this code does not compile with Clang 3.4, does it suffer from the same problem?

Comment: @qdii: If your installation of clang 3.4 is using gcc's libstdc++, then yes.  However if clang is using libc++ (http://libcxx.llvm.org), then the above will compile.

Answer (score 3):

An implementation may omit a copy operation resulting from a return statement, even if the copy constructor has side effects. In this case you may just have to explicitly move.

```
fstream open_user_file() const
{
    fstream f;

    /*...*/

    return std::move(f);
}
```

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
>   object, even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object
>   have side effects.

...

And this is where it says the copy constructor must be accessible:

> ***When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met*** or would be met save for the fact that the source
>   object is a function parameter, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, ***overload resolution to
>   select the constructor for the copy is first performed*** as if the object were designated by an rvalue. If overload
>   resolution fails, or if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is not an rvalue reference to
>   the object’s type (possibly cv-qualified), overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an
>   lvalue. [ Note: This two-stage overload ***resolution must be performed regardless of whether copy elision will
>   occur. It determines the constructor to be called if elision is not performed, and the selected constructor
>   must be accessible even if the call is elided.***

Comment: Note that GCC 4.8 hasn't implemented moveable file streams. This will compile in Clang 3.4 though.